# d3 - scaleTime by week

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working with d3 to recreate a chart in the web. I have a line chart working with proper scale on the y axis. I now need to be able to set the scale on the x axis which works with dates.

What I want is to be able to print out the dates along with the week from the total similar to this example in excel:
[image: Excel example]

Here is what I currently get:
[image: d3 example]

Here is my current class:

***Chart.js***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import { scaleLinear, scaleTime } from 'd3-scale';
import { max, extent } from 'd3-array';
import { select } from 'd3-selection';
import { line } from 'd3-shape';
import { axisBottom, axisLeft } from 'd3-axis';

import '../App.css';

const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 };

class Chart extends Component {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.createChart();
  }

  componentDidUpdate = () => {
    this.createChart();
  }

  createChart = () => {
    switch (this.props.type) {
      case 'bar': this.createBarChart(); break;
      case 'line-date': this.createDateLineChart(); break;
      default: break;
    }
  }

  createBarChart = () => {
    const node = this.node;
    const dataMax = max(this.props.data);
    const yScale = scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, dataMax])
      .range([0, this.props.size[1]]);

    select(node)
      .selectAll('rect')
      .data(this.props.data)
      .enter()
      .append('rect');

    select(node)
      .selectAll('rect')
      .data(this.props.data)
      .exit()
      .remove();

    select(node)
      .selectAll('rect')
      .data(this.props.data)
      .style('fill', '#fe9922')
      .attr('x', (d, i) => i * 25)
      .attr('y', d => this.props.size[1] - yScale(d))
      .attr('height', d => yScale(d))
      .attr('width', 25);
  }

  createDateLineChart = () => {
    const node = this.node;
    var svg = select(node);

    var width = +svg.attr('width') - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = +svg.attr('height') - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var g = svg.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');


    var x = scaleTime()
      .rangeRound([0, width]);

    var y = scaleLinear()
      .rangeRound([height, 0]);

    var d3Line = line()
      .x(function (d) { return x(d.date); })
      .y(function (d) { return y(d.number); });

    var data = [];
    for (var item of this.props.data) {
      data.push({
        date: moment(item.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD').toDate(),
        number: +item.number
      });
    }

    x.domain(this.props.xscale !== undefined ? this.props.xscale : extent(data, function (d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain(this.props.yscale !== undefined ? this.props.yscale : extent(data, function (d) { return d.number; }));

    // X axis
    g.append('g')
      .call(axisLeft(y))
      // Set axis label
      .append('text')
      .attr('fill', '#000000')
      .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
      .attr('transform-y', '-50%')
      .attr('y', -30) // Left
      .attr('x', (height / 2) * -1) // Down
      .attr('font-weight', 'bold')
      .attr('text-anchor', 'center')
      .text(this.props.labels.x);

    // Y axis
    g.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
      .call(axisBottom(x))
      // Removes axis line
      // .select('.domain')
      // .remove()
      // Set axis label
      .append('text')
      .attr('fill', '#000000')
      .attr('transform-x', '-50%')
      .attr('y', 30) // Down
      .attr('x', (width / 2)) // Left
      .attr('font-weight', 'bold')
      .attr('text-anchor', 'center')
      .text(this.props.labels.y);

    // Path / Line
    g.append('path')
      .datum(data)
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('stroke', 'steelblue')
      .attr('stroke-linejoin', 'round')
      .attr('stroke-linecap', 'round')
      .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
      .attr('d', d3Line);
    // });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <svg ref={node => this.node = node}
        width={1280}
        height={720} />
    );
  }
}

export default Chart;
```

What do I need to do to make d3 set the scale so I can set the date to `W1 - 08/09/17` etc.?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of data what you use for your chart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the result you want manipulating the axis generator.

First, to show one tick per week, use `ticks`:

```
.ticks(d3.timeWeek.every(1))
```

Then, to show the number of week before the week, use the second argument in the `tickFormat`:

```
.tickFormat(function(d, i) {
    return "W" + (i + 1) + " - " + d3.timeFormat("%d/%m/%y")(d)
});
```

Since we are showing just one tick per week, the second argument (which is the index of each tick) will be the week number (adding 1, since the index is zero based).

Here is a demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var scale = d3.scaleTime()
  .range([40, 560])
  .domain([new Date(2017, 0), new Date(2017, 1)]);
var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
  .ticks(d3.timeWeek.every(1))
  .tickFormat(function(d, i) {
    return "W" + (i + 1) + " - " + d3.timeFormat("%d/%m/%y")(d)
  });
var gX = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="100"></svg>
```